# Angular 2 - Unable to assign return value from http subscribe() method to a global variable inside component

Tags: json, http, angular, get

I am getting a JSON file using http.get in angular 2.

recent.service.ts:

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
//import { Observable } from '../../../../../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable';
import { Observable } from '../../../../../../node_modules/rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';



@Injectable()
export class RecentService {

    private _url = 'http://localhost:3001/api/uploadedFiles';

    constructor(private _http: Http) {


    }

    getJson() {

        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map(res => res.json());

    }

}
```

recent.component.ts:

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, NgStyle} from             '@angular/common';
    import {RecentService} from './recent.service';
    import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http'; 
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


   @Component({
    selector: 'recent',
    pipes: [],
    providers: [RecentService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    styleUrls: ['/app/pages/content/components/recent.styles.css'],   //might need to change reference   
    template: require('./recent.html') // `<strong>My edit page</strong>`
   })
   export class Recent implements OnInit{

      allFiles;
      public allFiles_error:Boolean = false;
      openModalWindow:boolean=false;
      images = [];
      currentImageIndex:number;
      opened:boolean=false;
      imgSrc:string;

   constructor(private _recentService: RecentService) {
       this._recentService.getJson()
           .subscribe(data => { 
             this.allFiles = data;
             console.log("allFiles: ", this.allFiles);
             console.log(this.allFiles.length);
             for(var i = 0; i < this.allFiles.length; i++) {
               this.images.push({
               thumb: this.allFiles[i].url,
               img: this.allFiles[i].url,
               description: "Image " + (i+1)
              });
             }
             console.log("Images: ", this.images);
            },
           err => { this.allFiles_error = true },
           () => console.log('Completed!')
    );

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.images.length);
    console.log(this.images);
    console.log(typeof this.images);
  }
    //this is the function where I want to access this.images
    openGallery(index) {
      if(!index) {
        this.currentImageIndex = 1;
      }
      this.currentImageIndex = index;
      this.opened = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
         if (i === this.currentImageIndex ) {
         this.imgSrc = this.images[i].img;
         break;
       }
    }
    console.log(this.imgSrc);
  }
```

this.allFiles is an array of JSON objects. I'm trying to store selected data from this.allFiles to this.images. I would also like to access this.images as a global variable throughout my component but haven't been able to do so because of async calls with http.get(). I did try the async pipe within my html but that also led to an error. Is there a way to access this.images globally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make something 'global' you can create a shared component/module with static members and storage and use if from all other components.

Answer (score 2):

I have little experience with TypeScript and Angular2 but I guess that your problem is with the arrow functions and the `this` keyword. Whenever you use brackets on an error function the `this` inside of it starts referencing the function itself, and not the desired upper class. Do the same for your error handling as well.

Also remove the call from your constructor and use `ngOnInit` for that.

Please try something like this and let me know:

```
export class Recent implements OnInit{
    allFiles;
    public allFiles_error:Boolean = false;
    openModalWindow:boolean=false;
    images = [];
    currentImageIndex:number;
    opened:boolean=false;
    imgSrc:string;

    constructor(private _recentService: RecentService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._recentService.getJson().subscribe(
            data => initData(data),
            err => handleError(),
            () => console.log('Completed!'));
    }

    initData(data){
        this.allFiles = data;
        console.log("allFiles: ", this.allFiles);
        console.log(this.allFiles.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < this.allFiles.length; i++) {
            this.images.push({
            thumb: this.allFiles[i].url,
            img: this.allFiles[i].url,
            description: "Image " + (i+1)
            });
        }
        console.log("Images: ", this.images);
        console.log(this.images.length);
        console.log(this.images);
        console.log(typeof this.images);
    }

    handleError() {
        this.allFiles_error = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried out your code, I'm still having the problem where this.images returns an empty array. I think the main issue is that this.images is returned before it gets populated.

Comment: I don´t see where you are returning `this.images`

Comment: Currently, I'm just trying to log `this.images.length` inside `ngOnInit()` after the `.subscribe()` method which prints 0 on the console. Eventually, I need to access `this.images` inside my html as well as methods inside my component that directly use 'this.images` array.

Comment: That's not gonna work. At that point the array is empty because the subscribe is an async operation. You can may full access on my initData function, because it will only run when you got all your results back from the server.

Comment: I just added *ngIf="images" on my template so that the html only renders when images is defined. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to access the **this.allFiles** ?

You can add that to the template **without any pipe** because it's inside of subscribe from Observables, Angular2 knows to re-render the template and it will be updated.

If you need to access in other function from the component, then add the function calls inside the **.subscribe** function.

Comment: I'm only accessing `this.allFiles` in the `subscribe()` method when assigning selected values from this.allFiles to `this.images`. `this.images` logs values to console as expected within `.subscribe()`. The problem occurs when I'm trying to iterate over `this.images` inside of another function. Moreover, I'm trying to call those functions from my template.

Comment: I have edited the original post to show one of the function where I'm using the values from `this.images`. On the console, `this.imgSrc` shows up as undefined, probably due to the issue I'm having.

Comment: you cannot call those functions directly from the template, because this.images is not ready yet, it will be ready when subscribe callback is called. So the functions should be called from the subscribe, or if you need it in the template you need to add an *ngIf state which will render just when subscribe triggers so when this.images is available.

Comment: that helped. I just added *ngIf="images" on my template so that the html only renders when images is defined. Thank you for your answer!